# How to make text match not bring up false positives?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
if (URL.toLowerCase().match(/\.(gif)/g)) {
    alert('gif');
}

if (URL.toLowerCase().match(/\.(gifv)/g)) {
    alert('gifV');
}
```

What's happening is that when URL is a gifV ( example `imgur.com/dog.gifv` ), page loading gives me both alerts.

How do I make it only give me the GIFV alert when url is gifv?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a different way of extracting the extension would be easier. Using array functions: https://jsfiddle.net/wdvz34qb/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the superset of text first (`gifv`), and only check for the subset of text (`gif`) if the first doesn't find a match:

```
if (URL.toLowerCase().match(/\.(gifv)/g)) {
    alert('gifV');
} else if (URL.toLowerCase().match(/\.(gif)/g)) {
    alert('gif');
}
```